# What's wrong with my prolog program for solving the 3 jugs of water puzzle?

Tags: prolog, dcg, water-jug-problem

Can anyone find why I can't have any true answers with my 'go' at this code? For example, I write `go(7,3,l)` and I suppose that it should move 3 litres of water to the second jug, but it is false according to prolog.  What's wrong?

```
:- dynamic go/3.
:- dynamic cur_state/1,init/5.
:- dynamic end_state/1, final/5.

cur_state(State):-State = state(10,0,0,7,l).
end_state(State):-State = state(0,3,3,0,r).

pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),move(D,C,r),state(D,C,D3,n,r)) :-
        D is D1-n,
        C is D2+n.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),move(D,C,l),state(D,C,D3,n,l)) :-
        D is D1-n,
        C is D2.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),move(D,C,r),state(D,D2,C,n,r)) :-
        D is D1-n,
        C is D3+n.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),move(D,C,r),state(D1,D,C,n,r)) :-
        D is D2-n,
        C is D3+n.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),move(D,C,l),state(D1,D,C,n,l)) :-
        D is D2-n,
        C is D1+n.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),move(D,C,l),state(D1,D,c,n,l)) :-
        D is D2-n,
        C is D3.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),move(D,C,r),state(C,D2,D,n,r)) :-
        D is D3-n,
        C is D1.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),move(D,C,l),state(D1,C,D,n,l)) :-
        D is D3-n,
        C is D2+n.
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),move(D,C,l),state(C,D2,D,n,l)) :-
        D is D3-n,
        C is D1+n.

carry(7,0).
carry(3,0).
carry(10,0).
carry(7,0).
carry(7,3).

legal(10,X,Y):-X+Y<10.
legal(X,Y,Z):-X+Y+Z<10.
legal(X,7,Y):-X+Y=<3.
legal(X,Y,3):-X+Y=<7.

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,r)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<7,C=<3,
        D22 is D2+n,
        D11 is D1-n,
    D3 is D33,
    n1 is n,
        D2=<7,D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,l)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<10,C=<100,
        D11 is D1-n,
    D22 is D2,
    D33 is D3,
        D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,r)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<10,C<3,
        D11 is D1-n,
        D33 is D3+n,
    D22 is D2,
        D1=<10,D3=<3,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,l)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<7,C=<3,
        D22 is D2-n,
        D33 is D1+n,
        D11 is D1,
    D2=<7,D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,r)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<7,C=0,
        D22 is D2-n,
        D33 is D3+n,
        D11 is D1,
    D2=<7,D3=<3,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,l)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<7,C=<100,
        D22 is D2-n,
    D33 is D3,
    D11 is D1,    
    D2=<7,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,l)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<3,C=<7,
        D22 is D2+n,
        D33 is D3-n,
        D11 is D1,
    D3=<3,D2=<7,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,r),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,l)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<3,C=<100,
        D11 is D1+n,
        D33 is D3-n,
        D22 is D2,
    D3=<3,D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).

newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,r)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<3,C=<100,
        D33 is D3-n,
        D22 is D2,
    D11 is D1,  
    D3=<3,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).


eisodos(_):- cur_state(State),write(State),nl.

init(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5):-assert(cur_state(State):-State = state(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),write('Arxikh:'),
   write(state(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),retractall(init(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),nl.

final(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5):-assert(end_state(State):-State = state(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),write('Telikh:'),
   write(state(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),retractall(init1(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)),nl.

go(Move1,Move2,Move3):-cur_state(State),newstate(State,NextState),
        pour(State,move(Move1,Move2,Move3), NextState),
        retractall(cur_state(State):-State = state(_,_,_,_,_)),asserta(cur_state(NextState)),
        ((end_state(NextState),write('Bravo!!!!')) ;(write(' ---*Eiste sthn katastash --- :'),write(NextState))),nl.
```

Comment: Seing that code does not give me the taste to learn prolog, sorry.

Comment: I can't find why your go predicate doesn't work but I kinda have to admit I can't find why your go predicate should work either... What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: i'm tyring to write a programm that simulates the problem of 3 jugs of water and the possible moves of water between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to correct it's basic syntax: variables must begin with uppercase, so for instance you must change this rule

```
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),move(D,C,r),state(D,C,D3,n,r)) :-
    D is D1-n,
    C is D2+n.
```

to

```
pour(state(D1,D2,D3,N,l),move(D,C,r),state(D,C,D3,N,r)) :-
    D is D1-N,
    C is D2+N.
```

and

```
newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,n,l),state(D11,D22,D33,n1,r)):-
        carry(M,C),
        M=<7,C=<3,
        D22 is D2+n,
        D11 is D1-n,
    D3 is D33,
    n1 is n,
        D2=<7,D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).
```

to

```
newstate(state(D1,D2,D3,N,l),state(D11,D22,D33,N1,r)):-
    carry(M,C),
    M=<7,C=<3,
    D22 is D2+N,
    D11 is D1-N,
    D3 is D33,
    N1 is N,
    D2=<7,D1=<10,
    legal(D1,D2,D3).
```

You should realize that N1 is valorized just in the first newstate/2 procedure: then correct the other instances of that rule.

Then you should remove the useless dynamic assertions: think about your actual assert/retractall usage: what you need is to change the **state** moving 'water' between 'jugs' at any step: so you should assert/retract state/5 while looping in go, from an initial state (assert this at start program), to a final acceptable state, to be tested in go to stop the cycle.

But this style based on state change leads to **very** difficult debugging. Try instead to remove altogheter the dynamic,assert/retractall, and pass around the state in your cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but if you don't mind read the comment i wrote @Mog and any ideas except of these will be usefull...

Comment: Did you tried to correct your program using the hints I wrote? Because any step I'd try would go along that way. Of course the simpler way to solve your problem could be to adapt (after understanding :) any of the correct solutions from Mog or mat. To be true I haven't tried these, but appears much more plausible than your code. The key to solve combinatorial problems (by brute force) is often the use of select/3 with an appropriate state representation

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer.I did tha changes you suggested and i have this when i'm trying go(7,3,r).:ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (7) newstate(state(10, 0, 0, 7, l), _G212) ?

But i'm not sure that i have explained correctly what i want from my programma to do..It's a programm that solves the water jugs problem but a programm that the user 'says' what to do and if the user says the right moves the problem is solved without algorithms etc..

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Mog's answer, I suggest to use iterative deepening if you want to find a shortest solution. The following is based on the code posted by @Mog (and thus solves the same problem that is slightly different from the one posted by OP). As we want to describe a list (of moves), DCG notation is convenient:

```
solution(Path) :- length(Path, _), phrase(path([0-3, 0-5, 8-8]), Path).

path(State) --> { equivalent(State, [0-3, 4-5, 4-8]) }.
path(State0) --> [From-To],
        { move(State0, State), State = [_-From, _-To, _] },
        path(State).

equivalent(State1, State2) :- forall(member(X, State1), member(X, State2)).

move(State, [NewX-From, NewY-To|NewRest]) :-
    select(X-From, State, Rest),
    X \== 0,
    select(Y-To, Rest, NewRest),
    Fillable is To - Y,
    ToFill is min(X, Fillable),
    NewY is Y + ToFill,
    NewX is X - ToFill.
```

Sample query:

```
?- solution(Ps).
Ps = [8-5, 5-3, 3-8, 5-3, 8-5, 5-3, 3-8] .
```

Answer (score 2):

Well so as I said in my comment, I kinda wouldn't know how to help you with your current work since there are so many wrong things in it. I'd advise you to read a nice tutorial about Prolog (such as [Learn Prolog now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)) so that you can grab the language basics. Here is a simple way to solve your problem if you're interested. If you don't want your problem to be spoiled, just don't read further : ] (the one I posted is about a 3/5/8 jugs and a 4/4 split).

```
go(Path) :-
    solve([0-3, 0-5, 8-8], [], [], Temp),
    reverse(Temp, Path).

solve(State, _Visited, Path, Path) :-
    equivalent(State, [0-3, 4-5, 4-8]).
solve(State, Visited, Acc, Path) :-
    move(State, NewState),
    NewState = [_-From, _-To|_],
    forall(member(Past, Visited), \+ equivalent(Past, NewState)),
    solve(NewState, [NewState|Visited], [From-To|Acc], Path).

equivalent(State1, State2) :-
    forall(member(X, State1), member(X, State2)).

move(State, [NewX-From, NewY-To|NewRest]) :-
    select(X-From, State, Rest),
    X \== 0,
    select(Y-To, Rest, NewRest),
    Fillable is To - Y,
    ToFill is min(X, Fillable),
    NewY is Y + ToFill,
    NewX is X - ToFill.
```

If you need explanations about the code once you've read a little more about prolog, don't hesitate!

Comment: Firts of all thank you! But my problem is that i want the user to 'write' the path by calling a 'function' that's what i was trying to do. For example i wanted in my programm the user to write go(7,3,0,3,r) and 3 litres to go in the second jug.Any ideas on that??