# If statement in prolog

Tags: prolog, water-jug-problem

Hello i have a problem with if statement. i have this

```
final(C1-W1,C2-W2,C3-W3):- 
    retractall(end_jug), 
    asserta( end_jug(C1,W1) ),
    asserta( end_jug(C2,W2) ),
    asserta( end_jug(C3,W3) ).
```

and this one

```
katastasi(L) :- 
    findall(X-W, jug(X,W), L0), sort(L0,L).
```

How can i have this check????:

```
    if(jug(C1,W1) == end_jug(C1,W1) && jug(C2,W2) == end_jug(C2,W2) && jug(C3,W3) == end_jug(C3,W3)) write('Congrats').
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should've mentioned [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030462/3-jugs-of-water-in-prolog-doesnt-work). :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
is_final_state :- 
  katastasi(S), writeln(S),
  S=[C1-W1,C2-W2,C3-W3],
  (  end_jug(C1,W1),
     end_jug(C2,W2),
     end_jug(C3,W3)
  -> writeln('Congrats!')
  ;  W1+W2+W3 < 6
  -> writeln('WARNING: not enough water left!'),
     fail
  ).
```

You should've mentioned [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030462/3-jugs-of-water-in-prolog-doesnt-work). This code is a part of the code in the answer there.

Your code is in Prolog, but the check you asked about was in "Basic". Let go of the Basic mentality. :) Prolog does the checks for you, as part of unification.

The value `6` in the code above should be calculated really, according to the final values the user specifies by calling `final` at the start fo the game. The final value (of each `end_jug` fact) can be retrieved just like the current value (of each `jug` fact) is retrieved by `jugsState` predicate (which I assume is now called `katastasi`).

Now you must complete your game by writing the `stop` predicate, which should do the cleanup (i.e. call `retract` on all the asserted facts). You can even make an `undo` predicate. :)

Comment: and the [previouser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748867/whats-wrong-with-my-prolog-program-for-solving-the-3-jugs-of-water-puzzle) question too x)

Comment: @Mog I meant that this new question refers to the code from the answer to that preious question, so must be (is easier) seen in that context. He wanted a "game", it turns out. Ah, and now I see there's a naming conflict there. :) will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the conditions joined by `,` under a new predicate:

```
win(C1, W1, C2, W2, C3, W3):-
    jug(C1,W1) \== end_jug(C1,W1),
    jug(C2,W2) \== end_jug(C2,W2),
    jug(C3,W3) \== end_jug(C3,W3).
```

Then use this predicate when needed.

```
finish(C1, W1, C2, W2, C3, W3):-
    win(C1, W1, C2, W2, C3, W3),
    write('Congrats').
```

Or write it as a whole:

```
finish(C1, W1, C2, W2, C3, W3):-
    jug(C1,W1) \== end_jug(C1,W1),
    jug(C2,W2) \== end_jug(C2,W2),
    jug(C3,W3) \== end_jug(C3,W3),
    write('Congrats').
```

Comment: `jug(C1,W1) == end_jug(C1,W1)` can never succeed. This is Prolog, not Basic.

Comment: `jug(C1,W1) \== end_jug(C1,W1)` will succeed *always*.