# ERROR: Stream user_input:8:5 Syntax error: Operator expected in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have to write a simple expert system in Prolog for scheduling of classes. In this code part, I want that user add an instructor to system. For this, reading two input value but I am getting this error.

```
addinstructor() :-    
    read(id),
    read(courseid),     
    assert(instructor(id, courseid)),    
    write("added").
```

Query:

```
?- addinstructor().
5
cse102.
```

Then, I am getting operator expected error.
How do i fix this to work my code?

Comment: Hi, I will  recommend reading [Ask]. Tell us more about what is the prupuse, the expected result , the context, the input, the output. Everything that make sense for your question.

Comment: There is no need for the empty parentheses after `addinstructor`, either in the definition or in the query that calls it. I would recommend you remove them. Prolog variables **MUST** be capitalized; `id` and `courseid` are *atoms*, not variables, and this is a problem for your code. Also, `assert/1` is non-standard, please use `asserta/1` or `assertz/1`, which give you control over the order of the facts in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Daniel Lyons . Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) reads Prolog terms not raw data. Prolog terms end with a period.

So if instead of entering `5` if you enter `5.` you will not get the error.

Instead of using the predicates found in [Term reading and writing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=termrw), e.g. `read/1`, you should use the predicates in [Primitive character I/O](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chario) for reading characters or [Predicates that operate on strings](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=string-predicates) for reading strings, e.g. [read_string/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_string/3)

To answer your next question of how do I implement this, see [Prolog - Write out facts and reading a users input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322558/1243762) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53374502/1243762).